# NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please give me suggestion, How can I solve solve this problem..

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Weight" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
  NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

I am getting output :

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a81cf0
2012-05-16 09:54:21.480 MedzioSearch[2188:f803] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a81cf0
```

Answer (score 2):

What kind of objects are in `arrayToSort`? What is the type of their "Weight" property?

At a guess, some of the objects have a Weight property which is an `NSString` while some have a Weight property which is an `NSNumber`.  As a consequence, the sort is trying to do something like `[someString localizedStandardCompare:someNumber]`.  Internal to `-[NSString localizedStandardCompare:]`, it's invoking `-length` on the argument which is an `NSNumber` and doesn't recognize that selector.

By the way, property names should begin with a lowercase letter unless they begin with an acronym or initialism (like "URL" or "TIFF").  So, your property should be named "weight", not "Weight".

Comment: Thanks for reply.I am using @"Weight" as NSString.Please provide me a better solution in NSString format.

Comment: As I say, I doubt that all of the "Weight" properties are giving `NSString`s. Try putting this code in and see what it logs: `NSLog(@"%@", [arrayToSort valueForKeyPath:@"Weight.class"]);`

Comment: It worked? My suggestion was intended to diagnose the problem, not fix it.